# Charging sphere with induction

Tags: electrostatics, charge

[image]

In the above picture, when we connect the positive side or negative side of the sphere to ground, electrons go to ground.

Why isn't there any difference between the situations when the negative side is connected and when the positive side is connected to the ground?

Comment: If you ground with a wire the sphere that has previously been negatively charged by induction to the positive ground terminal, the electrons flow in the opposite direction. Hence through any and all ground connections from the positive terminal.

Comment: sphere is neutral. I want to charge sphere with induction. my question is :

Comment: why when connect positive side of sphere to ground, electrons go from sphere to ground?

Comment: Then I apologize for not understanding the question. The direction of the current, assuming that there is current, or flow of electrons in the unit of time, is by convention the positive one, i.e. the protons that move from the positive to the negative pole. The real direction is the opposite, i.e. it is the electrons that move and not the protons.

Comment: i tell. when near negative rod to neutral sphere and polarize it, now when connect positive side or negative side of sphere to ground. electrons go to ground.why?

Comment: For the difference in potential (lower potential-sphere charge negatively) towards the higher potential (ground). Your sphere is not neutral for the induction effect.

Comment: Look this picture here: https://www.peoplephysics.com/images/leggifisiche/fulmini1.gif. Your picture is the same phenomenon of the lightning.

Comment: excuse me for repeat. I tell why no different between negative side to ground with positive side to ground? in two cases electron go to ground.

Comment: i have edited my question and picture.

Comment: when charging a sphere by induction using a (-) charged object , and we put it to the right side of the sphere, electrons are pushed to the left side , so we ground the left side and the excess electrons escape. but what if we grounded the right side ( which has less electrons than usual ) wouldn't electrons flow from the ground to neutralise this side?

Comment: When a body is negatively (positively) charged there is an excess of negative (positive) charges but it does not mean that there are no positive (negative) charges on the right or left side that you take into consideration.The bar is negatively charged and the sphere has an excess of negative charges, even if positive charges are present. The situation (2) or (3) are identical.

Comment: when grounding positive side, electrons in the positive side go to ground? then electron in the left side come and replace?

Answer (score 2):

I think a negative rod likes to repel electrons on the right side of the sphere. Therefore the right side is positive and left side negative.
Now when connecting the positive side to the ground... it is created large space rod to repel extra electron to the ground.

Comment: I remind you that the right side has positive charges but there are always negative charges on the right side (there is a predominance of negative charges).  Basically, your reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The direction of electrons flow should be opposite to each other, in the diagrams shown in the question. The earth has zero potential. Electrons flow from lower potential to higher potential and positive charges flow in conventional current direction, i.e. from higher potential to lower potential.